# What is the correct name for the header used to verify Shopify Webhooks?

Tags: shopify, webhooks

The documentation refers to the header name as `HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256`

Looking at webhook requests coming into my servers the header is named `x-shopify-hmac-sha256`

Which is the correct name? Is it case sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), HTTP headers are case-insensitive. See section 4.2 of the document, titled Message Headers.